# Intent Extension for Siri Shortcuts works in Sample App not in existing project

Tags: ios13, sirishortcuts, intents-extension

I am trying to use Intents Extension in my existing Obj-C project for conversational shortcuts in iOS 13. I have followed all the steps and the procedures work fine in a sample app.

But when I try it out in my existing application the intents fail to launch and it is automatically redirected to my parent app.

The console error is as follows

```
[Intents] -[INCache cacheableObjectForIdentifier:] Unable to find cacheable object with identifier intents-remote-image-proxy:?proxyIdentifier=2A439A9B-6D95-BFB2-FCE4-31408D1E677F.png&storageServiceIdentifier=com.apple.Intents.INImageServiceConnection in cache.
```

Has anyone faced such an issue with intents? Please share your thoughts on this.

Additional Info:
The intent is registered. Have implemented the 'handle' 'resolve' methods and have also declared them in the interface.

Have the extension's min deployment target same as the parent (which created an issue that I had missed previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was created due to setting up 'Copy only when installing' boolean as 'true' in 'Embed App Extensions' under 'Build Phases'. It was resolved once the check was made 'false'.

[image: Uncheck this]